# Can't resolve hosts in browser. DNS seems good. Issue crosses browsers. Other PCs ok

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, ipv6

I am wondering why I can't browse most websites. I can reach Google sites, Netflix, and Facebook, but nothing else. Everything works on other sites. This is true of Edge and Chrome including in incognito. This started at some point today. Seems to work fine on other networks. It's just the main network I use, and only on this one machine, that's having a rough go.

nslookup works.

I can't resolve websites directly from their ip.

Everything works fine on other machines, so it doesn't seem to be anything weird with the modem or ISP.

Last successful update was kb4551762 on March 14. 1 failed update, kb4537572 March 17, was cumulative update or .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8

Tried:

- using the windows diagnostic (hah!)
- rebooting
- resetting the network adapter (disable/enable)
- uninstalling and reinstalling the adapter.
- disabling firewall
- disabling ipv6 (no ipv6, no internet)
- verified not trying to connect to a proxy.
- clearing the chrome-internals
- route -f
- netsh winsock reset
- ran full windows security scan. Tried installing malwarebytes, but apparently their 
  installer needs to download stuff and that's just not happening.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to move the hosts file from its original location to, say your Desktop (not delete it entirely), then reboot? Could be a rule in it that prevents you from connecting to those websites or domains. You can also try to create a new standard user account on your PC, log on to this account and see if the problem persists. If not, then your profile is faulty somehow. If yes, it's system-wide. EDIT: the latest KB has proven to wreak havoc on some machines, too...

Comment: @Didier had checked the hosts file, but tried moving as you suggested. The issue persisted.  Creating a new profile was a good idea, thank you for that. The issue is system wide. I also uninstalled the last KB and that doesn't seem to have changed anything. I attempted to reset windows with the 'keep everything' but something is deeply wrong because its failing halfway through--after the reboot. Tried `sfc /scannow`, but it didn't find any issues. Just trying a reset with full erase now. I'm a bit skeptical I'll have better luck with that.

Comment: Check your firewall if you haven't already. Could be that a rule has been set by, either a Windows update or a program you uninstalled, and it's still in place. Check in the outgoing traffic under Advanced firewall. The fact that if you cut IPv6, you have no connectivity at all (did I understand correctly?) is intriguing. It might mean only the IPv6 versions of the websites you want to visit can be reached. Google has both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses for its search page, but the problem could be in how your router handles IPv4 outgoing requests . Check your IPv4 configuration in your adapter too.